# How are resources connected to controllers without a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, http-verbs

I am writing a basic application that scrapes data. I have the following in my `routes.rb`.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
 namespace :api, path: '/' do
   resources :apps, :only => :show
 end
end
```

In controllers I have something like this although I am not sure how are resources connected to Controller.

```
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    puts "this works"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  def apps
    puts "my app"
  end

end
```

Also, I dont have a `Model`. Does that mean that in my resources `:apps` calls a method in AppsController called `apps`?
If I wanted it t call apps then how's it possible ?

- how does a controller in rails know what route does it belong to
- I am trying to add a GET /apps?filter=5 that returns my scraped data in the form of JSON and with filter as parameter to that it means that return 5 JSON objects to me

Comment: No! It calls the `show` method.

Answer (score 1):

Routing simply maps URLs to a controller/action, the existence of a model with the same name does not matter.

To get to the `apps` action that you defined in the AppsController you need to define a route that maps to `apps#apps` < This syntax means `AppsController`, `apps` action.

An example of a route that would map to the AppsController `apps` action:

```
get '/apps', to: "apps#apps"
```

This is a weird example. It's not conventional to have a `def apps` action inside `AppsController`, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this action?

If you want a rest call to /apps that returns a JSON list of apps, then this all you need to do.

## router

```
resources :apps, only: [:index]
```

## controller

```
class AppsController < ActionController::Base

  def index
    puts "This is the index route in AppsController"
  end

end
```

In the router, when you specify `resource :apps, only: [:index]`. This routes the request `GET /apps` to `AppsController#index`

Comment: I want to have a rest call that returns Json for /apps

Answer (score 1):

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
   namespace :api, path: '/' do
       get :apps, to: "apps#apps", on: :collection #-> api.url.com/apps
   end
end
```

A much more coherent way to do it would be...

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
   namespace :api, path: '/' do
       resources :apps #-> api.url.com/apps -> apps#index
   end
end
```

---

I think you're getting confused with how Rails works, especially with your data.

I post this all the time, maybe it will help you:

[image]

As you can see, your request is not tied to a specific "model", nor is a controller bound to it either. I'll explain the importance of the [**`MVC`** (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) aspect of rails in a minute.

Your thought process is that each request / resource has to have a corresponding model / dataset to pull from. Strictly, this is not the case, although many would believe it to be.

Remember that Rails is just an application *framework* - it has to work with all the same protocols & restrictions as the other frameworks & languages out there.

When you send a request to Rails (through your browser URL), it takes that request, and matches it to the appropriate *controller*. This controller action will then pull data from your model (if you've set it up like that), render the *view* with that data, and return the processed HTML to the browser.

Thus, you don't have to have a *model* bound to a particular controller action, or anything. You just need to make sure your controllers & views are mapped accordingly.

---

**OOP**

[image]

I think the part you're getting hooked up on is the *object orientated* nature of Ruby / Rails.

Although every part of the Rails framework is meant to work with *objects*, this only applies on a request-basis.

For example, whilst it's typically recommended to keep your controllers [*resourceful*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web), you don't have to adhere to that methodology if you don't want to. Many newbies don't know the difference.

Thus, when you use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
 namespace :api, path: '/' do
   resources :apps, only: :show #-> api.url.com/:id -> apps#show
 end
end
```

... what you're denoting is a controller bound by its resourceful nature. This would typically be expected to use *model* data, but it's not essential...

[image]

Comment: How does controller know that route is for him if I don't declare the /apps way as rest call from r /apps would just be once and that's how it detects

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

> In controllers I have something like this although I am not sure how
>   are resources connected to Controller.

`Rails.application.routes.draw` provides a DSL which hooks into Rack (the interface between the HTTP server and Rails). It generates rules for where to route the response from Rack.

The DSL is provides has a lot of ways to do the same things. In this example, the `resources :apps, :only => :show` line basically says you want to generate all of the REST verbs for the `AppsController`, but you only want the `:show` verb, so the router will only generate a route to `AppsController#show`. Note that you can run `rake routes` to get a list of your routes.

> Also, I dont have a Model. Does that mean that in my resources :apps
>   calls a method in AppsController called apps? If I wanted it t call
>   apps then how's it possible ?

Models are totally separate abstractions. Once the code reaches your controller you are in plain Ruby land until you return out of that controller action. Models are simply plain Ruby objects with the ability to talk to the database.

In your code if you wanted to call `apps` from the `show` method (or action) then you can just call it from there since it's in the same scope.

> how does a controller in rails know that ok that is my route. In this case, apps

I'm not sure I understand this question, could you elaborate?

> I am trying to add a GET /apps?filter=5 that returns my scraped data in the form of JSON and with filter as parameter to that it means
>   that return 5 JSON objects to me

For one, you'll need to add a route for `/apps`. There are several ways you can do this. Here's one approach. I'm going to call it `index` instead of `apps` since that's more conventional:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/apps' => 'apps#index'

# app/controllers/apps_controller.rb
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    limit = params[:filter].to_i
    @users = User.first(limit) # Implement this however you wish
    respond_with(@users)
  end
end
```

My syntax might be a little off here with the `respond_to` and `respond_with`, but it should explain how the controller routes

Comment: I don't have a model remember so @users = User.first does not make sense in my cAse.

Comment: Right, so you could replace that with whatever call is providing your JSON. I just used it as an example. You can use `respond_to` as in your example or use `respond_with` using a responder object (http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Responder.html)